# WhatsApp group member's name not changing

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I recently edited a friend's name in my contacts. Though the private chats shows the edited name, in groups (xxx is typing) where xxx is the same old name. What should I do to change this?

Comment: I thought WhatsApp shows users' name (the one the user put in the configuration screen)  instead of contact name (the one in your contacts list)

Comment: The 'User Name' is displayed only if the person is not in your contacts.After you add the person to your contacts, his/her name will be displayed as whatever you've given in your contacts.